Updating Firestore Documents Using Firebase Cloud Functions is Extremely Slow
I am trying to update documents using Firebase Cloud Functions. My document updates do not need to consider existing values, and since they primarily involve single document updates with minimal risk of conflicts, I am proceeding without transaction handling.
The issue is that even a single test case takes approximately 3 minutes to complete. As a junior developer, I have never experienced such delays with Cloud Functions before, and I am struggling to identify the root cause of the problem.
Below is my full code and the logs generated from it:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.authenticator = functions.region('asia-northeast1').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const startTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("Function execution started at: ", new Date().toISOString());

  if (req.method !== "POST") {
    console.log("Method Not Allowed");
    return res.status(405).send("Method Not Allowed");
  }

  const data = req.body;

  if (!data || !data.data || !Array.isArray(data.data)) {
    console.log("Bad Request");
    return res.status(400).send("Bad Request");
  }

  res.status(200).send("Processing...");
  console.log("Process started at: ", new Date().toISOString());

  for (const item of data.data) {
    if (!item || !item.phoneNum || !item.authCode) {
      console.log("Invalid data: ", item);
      continue;
    }

    try {
      const updateStart = new Date().getTime();
      console.log("Update started for authCode: ", item.authCode, " at: ", new Date().toISOString());

      await admin.firestore().collection("auth").doc(item.authCode).update({
        phoneNum: item.phoneNum,
        verified: true,
        timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      });

      const updateEnd = new Date().getTime();
      console.log("Success: ", item.authCode, " at: ", new Date().toISOString(), " Update took: ", (updateEnd - updateStart) / 1000, " seconds");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Error processing ${item.authCode}:`, err);
    }
  }

  const endTime = new Date().getTime();
  console.log("Process ended at: ", new Date().toISOString());
  console.log("Total execution time: ", (endTime - startTime) / 1000, " seconds");
});


Function execution started  Function execution started at: 2024-07-09T21:28:39.167Z


Process started at: 2024-07-09T21:28:39.188Z


Update started for authCode: 519504f79458497cb8c4709739fbc877 at: 2024-07-09T21:28:39.188Z


Function execution took 80 ms, finished with status code: 200


Success: 519504f79458497cb8c4709739fbc877 at: 2024-07-09T21:31:36.657Z


Update took: 177.469 seconds


Process ended at: 2024-07-09T21:31:36.957Z


Total execution time: 177.79 seconds

The region for my Cloud Functions is asia-northeast1, and Firestore is in asia-northeast3. I changed the regions due to concerns about potential region-related issues, but I have previously handled updates quickly even in the us-central1 region.
For your reference, my code receives data processed by Gmail through a POST request from Google Apps Scripts.

How many documents are you updating for (const item of data.data) {?

@FrankvanPuffelen
I conducted a test to update a single document. The 3 minutes mentioned were literally spent updating just one document.

You're sending the res.status(200).send("Processing..."); before updating Firestore. Given that, you're lucky if any of the document updates make it through at all.
Move the code that sends the response to the client until after you've updated all the documents.

In addition, you are now using await on each call to update the database, which means that all updates are executed sequentially - one after the other. Since the data doesn't seem to require this, it's gonna be faster if you update them all in parallel. The easiest way to do that is to gather all the updateDoc promises in an array and then await Promise.all(...) on that array.

console.log("Process started at: ", new Date().toISOString());

const promises = [];
for (const item of data.data) {
  if (!item || !item.phoneNum || !item.authCode) {
    console.log("Invalid data: ", item);
    continue;
  }

  try {
    promises.push(admin.firestore().collection("auth").doc(item.authCode).update({
      phoneNum: item.phoneNum,
      verified: true,
      timestamp: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    }));
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error processing ${item.authCode}:`, err);
  }
}

await Promise.all(promises);

const endTime = new Date().getTime();
console.log("Process ended at: ", new Date().toISOString());
console.log("Total execution time: ", (endTime - startTime) / 1000, " seconds");

res.status(200).send("Processing...");


I implemented logic to process all requests in parallel using Promise, but the same issue occurred. Therefore, I wrote the code above as a potential solution. For actual use, I will likely utilize Promise. Thank you for your advice.

Also, sending the POST response early is an intended behavior. Google Apps Scripts have a limited quota for function execution time, so it was intended to send the data and then terminate immediately.

Additionally, I remembered an important point. In the previous code where the POST response was not sent early, Firestore document updates took approximately 5 seconds. It seems the POST response might be causing the issue. Is there a way to send the POST response early as intended while ensuring that Firestore updates are processed correctly?

Would it be better to upload a new question for this? I am not very familiar with Stack Overflow.

"sending the POST response early is an intended behavior" It  may have been intentional on your part, but changes how Cloud Functions responds. Once a complete response has been sent to the caller, it may terminate the container at any time - so there's a good chance your database calls don't get the chance to finish. --- If you don't want the caller to wait for the call to finish, implement it that way - by not making the caller wait, rather than by aborting the server action.
